# django http response 204 redirecting to blank page only in safari

Tags: javascript, django, http, django-views, http-status-code-204

I have a view button that triggers a javascript function. The JS function is made to display a modal popup and then redirect to a URL that returns HTTP 204 response. `return HttpResponse(status=204)`.

this is the js code

```
function count(){
    image_popup.style.display = "block";
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    window.location.href = "/image_info/view_count";
}
```

This code is working fine in chrome and firefox but in safari, ***204 response is redirecting to a new blank page.***

In other browsers, the 204 response is not redirecting the page and displaying the modal popup just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like intended in Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70226

Comment: Yea, I see..do you have any workarounds for this problem? any alternative solutions?

Comment: It'll be great if you can also provide some solution to the problem :).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).